# How to set ActionBar logo from URL?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a link which contains an image. Usually with `fresco` I can parse the link and set the image. But, in this case I need to set that image as an icon to `ActionBar`. 
I've tried this, but it must be `drawable` and as I said I only have the link to the image.

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.rose_logo));
```

I access the `ActionBar` this way because I need it in `fragment`.

Comment: show how do you obtaining image. as a Bitmap in some callback? here you presented setting fixed drawable from resources

Comment: This is how I used to do it when it was in my application as a `drawable`. But, at the moment I only have an URL which leads to the image.

Comment: then you have to implement some lib (fastest way) for obtain this image, as a Bitmap probably. [you can do this with Fresco](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476677/using-facebooks-fresco-to-load-a-bitmap) but there  are better libs for this

Comment: How can I add fresco to the action bar on the far left and show/hide that icon accordingly?

Comment: what is `fresco`... Facebook's lib or anything else? show more code with your url

Comment: Yes, `fresco` is a library such as `Picasso` or `Glide`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy! Here is a pretty easy way [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). You can find the description of this git on the github page of it. (on the link)

Comment: How is this easy with Picasso?

Comment: Try to make drawable from bitmap. Or save bitmap as a resource.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555218/adding-a-bitmap-to-the-drawable-resources

Comment: Hope this helped you.

Comment: Here is an example to load image with picasso to action bar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042325/can-i-load-a-picture-with-picasso-to-the-action-bar

Comment: This works, thank you! Please edit your answer without so many comments so it might help someone else!

Comment: this is a mess of an answer.